# Average by excluding data around a certain time during day in Excel

Tags: excel

I have one hour measurement data for a whole year. The timespamp is in column A.

I am trying to find a simple way to average the data by excluding all points at 6,7, and 8 AM. However, since these points pop up 365 times in the data, I am having problems with applying functions like averageifs etc.

Is there another way to do this?

Here's an example of two columns, timestamp in the first column and data in the 2nd.

```
10/25/13 0:00   186.7583777
10/25/13 1:00   181.5850511
10/25/13 2:00   182.5474936
10/25/13 3:00   182.7110036
10/25/13 4:00   182.9423479
10/25/13 5:00   183.4864833
10/25/13 6:00   182.4676709
10/25/13 7:00   181.2562128
10/25/13 8:00   183.1540795
```

Comment: Can you put an example of what your data looks like? i.e., Is it actually a time stamp, or does it look like "8 AM" as you posted?

Comment: Updated original post

Answer (score 1):

You could do it with an array formula, but I would probably put this formula in column C: `=if(or(hour(A:A)<6,hour(A:A)>8),B:B,"")` Drag that formula all the way down, then put this formula in cell D1 `=average(C:C)` If you want to look at other times, just change the formula in column C.

Comment: You can't use OR function like that in array formulas because OR returns a single result rather than array - to simulate OR in array functions you can use + as per my answer

Comment: That isn't an array formula. I stated that you could do it with an array formula, but this is how I would choose to do it.

Comment: Apologies, you are right - I misinterpreted the formula because it uses  A:A - now I realise that my [now edited] suggested method mimics yours +1

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((HOUR(A1:A8784)<>6)*(HOUR(A1:A8784)<>7)*(HOUR(A1:A8784)<>8)*B1:B8784)/SUMPRODUCT((HOUR(A1:A8784)<>6)*(HOUR(A1:A8784)<>7)*(HOUR(A1:A8784)<>8)*(B1:B8784<>""))
```

The range references were chosen since a 366 day year has 8784 hours; you might need to change them if your data doesn't start in A1; or if you are averaging more than one year in a column.

Answer (score 0):

An array formula like this will also work

`=AVERAGE(IF((HOUR(A2:A1000)<6)+(HOUR(A2:A1000)>8),IF(A2:A1000<>"",B2:B1000)))`

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

adjust ranges as required but preferable not to use whole columns in this formula